# Scope error: Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'scope'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, jquery-file-upload

I am trying to add Angular JS jQuery-File-Upload in my rails application.

To implement this, I am using

1. https://github.com/tors/jquery-fileupload-rails gem
2. Angular JS code from http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/angularjs.html

Now when I tried to add a new file it is showing an error

> Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'scope'

Here I am adding screenshot of the response that I got on file uploading.

[image]

Can anyone help me to figure out the error?

Answer (score 0):

Your "data" object clearly does not have any method "scope()". That's why the error. 
Are you trying to set some variable in "data" object to some angular "scope"? In that case double check, because there isn't any scope variable in 'data'. After you set it correctly you can either access it by data.scope, you don't need a method to retrieve it.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue, and after spending a few hours on it, I can suggest simply copying the sources from the demo page instead of trying to use the sources as they are provided in the download package.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and after a few hours dig into my code, I found the problem was  duplicate jquery.fileupload-angular.js files were included in my html page.

Remove the duplicated reference js file solved my problem straight away.